# How to print Arabic text using network printer

Tags: python-3.x

I have tried to implement an Arabic language by using network printer. But When I am printing through a local printer directly connected to the Windows workstation, I am printing Arabic successfully since it is using the Windows drivers through print driver.
But, When I am printing through a network printer directly from the printer ip, I am unable to print Arabic.

```
from escpos.printer import Network

kitchen = Network("192.168.1.111")
kitchen.text(" اطبع هذا النص")
kitchen.cut()
```

also, I have tried to solve this issue using encode("utf-8"). Here is the code,

```
from escpos.printer import Network

kitchen = Network("192.168.1.111")
kitchen.text(" اطبع هذا النص".encode("utf-8"))
kitchen.cut()
```

Comment: Which error occurs when you are trying to print it like that? Also, from the official documentation: "The text has to be encoded in the currently selected codepage.
        The input text has to be encoded in unicode."

Comment: Thank you for your response. It is not giving me any error.. It is printing ?????? instead of Arabic language without using encode.

Answer (score 0):

import arabic_reshaper
from bidi.algorithm import get_display

text = get_display(arabic_reshaper.reshape(u' اطبع هذا النص'))

kitchen.text(text)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).